# Who is causing the dreams/hallucinations this character experiences?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, batman-v-superman-dawn-of-justice

Simple question: who is causing the dreams/hallucinations that Bruce Wayne experiences throughout the movie? If not a person, then what?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most popular and likely theory is that this visions are caused by The Flash's time travel.

We see The Flash in that scene, reaching out from a time portal, talking to Bruce about coming back too soon:

> Am I too soon?
>   DAMN!
>   I'm too soon!

Now, what Bruce is actually experiencing is up for a little bit of debate, but the [prevailing theory](http://screenrant.com/batman-v-superman-knightmare-not-dream/) is that Bruce having his memories of a [possible future/alternate timeline](http://www.cinemablend.com/new/What-Actually-Happening-Crazy-Flash-Scene-From-Dawn-Justice-120907.html) (a Flashpoint or a Time Boom) mingle in with his own.

This is a concept that's [been explored](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/91141/31178) in Flash storylines before, most famously the Flashpoint Paradox.

Comment: I can buy that. I just watched the Flashpoint cartoon movie today, but usually it's the person who went back in time/caused the alteration who has the memories changed/integrated. From the BvS movie it seems like Lex also knows about the impending Darkseid invasion, but prior to him communicating with that demon thing near the end of the movie, how did he know?

Comment: @Derek I don't think he knew before that demon thing from the deleted scene, but he knew he didn't want Superman around. Also, that Flashpoint animated movie with Thomas Wayne Batman was pretty sweet